# 7zip recursively archive files in folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, 7zip

I need to archive all files but not folders that are inside a complex directory structure in a special way. Every subfolder (no matter how deep in the structure) will contain a zip file containing all files that used to be there.
If I use `7zip a -r -tzip files.zip \*.\*` this will put all the structure in a single root file (files and folders). Not good.

The solution is a batch script to recurse this structure, and for every folder found to create a zip file and delete the original files. But I only know how to make simple loops, not unlimited, and not in an unknown directory structure.

For example:
`for /F "tokens=1" %%u in ('dir /b /ad parentfolder') do (`
only lists the first level subdirectories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use ***(1)*** `FOR` command to iterate ***(2)*** over all `IN (*)` ***(3)*** directories `/D`,  ***(4)*** recursively `/R`
and ***(5)*** for each directory found `%%a`, 
***(6)*** apply `DO`  ***(7)*** the `7z` command to create a zip ***(8)*** named as the directory `%%~na.zip` ***(9)*** including all the contents of the directory `%%a\*`

```
for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
  7z a %%a\%%~na.zip %%a\*
)
```

***optionally***, you might want to erase the directory contents except the recently created zip file, place another `FOR` inside the previous `FOR`, after the `7z`

```
  for %%b in (*) do (
    if not %%b==%%~na.zip erase %%a\%%b
  )
```

Comment: why make another loop from the root when I can add a delete instruction immediately after the zip creation?

Comment: because you need to erase all **except** the zip itself